# asp.net core web api + could not load assembly exception

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a fresh ASP.net core web API.
I have referenced a project DLL in my web API  which is again referring to system.web.application.services.dll. 
The solution is building fine but getting the below exception when I call  POST verb from POSTMAN.

**Error details:**

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: It is most likely because the dll project type is not compatible with Core. What is the type of your project dll? And if is referencing any packages, then what is the type for each of those packages?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're referencing a .NET Framework 4.6 (or below) DLL in your .NET Core project. You have two options:

1. Add a reference to System.Web.ApplicationServices in your project. You may have to browse for the actual DLL (System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll), which you should be able to find in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319.
2. (I think this will work) Change your project to target the full .NET Framework instead of .NET Core.

You might run into other roadblocks after doing this, but it's a step in the right direction.